# Trouble setting my Setter using console.readline();

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out how to set my Setter via the readline from the console. Any help would be wonderful.

```
        MathOperations toDo = new MathOperations();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter first number to calculate");
        toDo.inputOne = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter second number to calculate");
        toDo.inputTwo = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Added: " + toDo.addNumbers(value1, value2));
```

---

```
class MathOperations
{
    private int inputOne;
    private int inputTwo;

    public int getInputOne()
    {
        return inputOne;
    }
    public void setInputOne(int value)
    {
        inputOne = value;
    }
    public int getInputTwo()
    {
        return inputTwo;
    }
    public void setInputTwo(int value)
    {
        inputTwo = value;
    }
    public int addNumbers(int number1, int number2)
    {
        int total;
        total = number1 + number2;
        return total;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a Proprety:

```
public int InputOne //bad name
{ get; set; }
```

This is an example of an *auto-property*

You can also do:

```
private int inputTwo;
public int InputTwo //bad name
{ 
   get
   {
      return inputTwo;
   }
   set
   {
      inputTwo = value;
   }
}
```

With one of those, the code you have will call the "set" function as you expect by writing:

```
InputOne = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
InputTwo = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

To address the comment about naming, in this case I would use `List<int> Operands` as the property, and have the readline commands add to this list. Then the addNumbers function just becomes:

```
return Operands.Sum();
```

This makes it much easier to add 3, 4, or even more numbers in the future without having to create more variables, etc. You could even read the inputs in a loop with this method.

Comment: Out of interest, what do you consider wrong with the names `InputOne` and `InputTwo`, bearing in mind that the `Tuple` classes use property names such as `Item1`, `Item2` etc. Would the names `Operand1` and `Operand2` be better?

Comment: Names with numbers at the end are a red flag for me. In an extremely simple program like this, I could understand it, and in the case you mentioned it makes sense (the other place I can think of is the names for generic delegate arguments). In general though, I would expect an array or collection instead of a list of variables with incrementing numbers added to the end as good style. I would personally prefer Operand1 and Operand2 since this is a math op, yes.

Comment: Another good reason to not use numbered variables is extensibility. What happens when you want to add three numbers? You need to modify the signature of your function, create an Operand3 variable, it starts to get really messy. With a list/array, you are already enumerating over the whole thing (hopfeully) and adding a third operand or argument is trivial (see my updated answer)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a property with a setter/getter you just use set-/getMethods. You need to have a property like this:

```
public int InputOne {
    set { inputOne = value; }
    get { return inputOne; }
}

public int InputTwo {
    set { inputTwo = value; }
    get { return inputTwo; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Auto-Implemented Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)

```
class MathOperations
{
    private int inputOne {get;set;}
    private int inputTwo {get;set;}

    public int addNumbers(int number1, int number2)
    {
        int total;
        total = number1 + number2;
        return total;
    }
}
```