# Use console.ReadLine() inside set property

Tags: c#, properties, console, console.readline

I am a beginner coder, I am currently learning c# and I was wondering is it possible to use Console.ReadLine(), inside the set part of the property and then use it like a method to read the user input, as follows:

```
class Employee
{
    protected int empID;
    public int EmployeeID
    {
        set
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter Employee ID:");
            this.empID = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }
    //more code here
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Employee employee1 = new Employee();
        employee1.EmployeeID;
        //more code here
    }
}
```

or the only option is to use Console.ReadLine() directly in the the "Main", as follows:

```
class Employee
{
    protected int empID;
    public int EmployeeID { set; }
    //more code here
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Employee employee1 = new Employee();
        employee1.EmployeeID = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        //more code here
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for all answers!

---

Thank you all for your answers! I can see now that this is a wrong way to write a code and I understand why. I thought that by using 'Console.ReadLine();' inside the 'set' property it will be easier to get the value from the user and I will not have to re-write this part:'

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter Employee ID:");
this.empID = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

each time I will ask the user for input. 
But I understand now why It should not be used.
Thank you again for all the answers and have a nice day!

Comment: Option #2 is the best. The first option is accessing the `get` (which isn't defined) so you'd actually get an error instead. Though you can do something like `mployee1.EmployeeID = 1;` instead where the `1` would just be thrown out and your prompt would come up and accept a value, this is really bad design.

Comment: I would honestly use a get and set and then parse the value out side of the setting of the property for a simple example on what I am talking about checkout this previous posting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262312/trouble-setting-my-setter-using-console-readline

Comment: The first option just feels very strange... IMO it's harder to read since your `Main` code looks like the property is doing nothing (although it isn't), making you look somewhere else for even a slight amount of understanding. If I gave you no context and said `myClass.SomeProperty;`, what would you think it's doing? You can really only guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can put a `Console.ReadLine()` inside a set. But this is very wrong.

C# properties are compiled similar to method, so you can put any available C# code inside a property, the compiler will allow you to do that. (The problem in your code is you're not writing the correctly call for the set).

But thinking in good practices and S.O.L.I.D, this is very wrong. Your second code snippet looks much better.

**Edited: About your code,**

if you run your code exactly like you wrote, I'll notice that your message `"Please enter Employee ID:"` is never displayed. This happens because a misconception about the `get` and `set` aspects of a property.

Look at this specific line:

```
employee1.EmployeeID;
```

This line of code is a `get` call on property `EmployeeID`. Maybe it's not obvious because you're not using the goted value. But this line is similar to:

```
var notUsedVar = employee1.EmployeeID;
```

To use a `set` operation of a property you NEED a attribution operation like:

```
employee1.EmployeeID = 0; // or
employee1.EmployeeID++; // or
employee1.EmployeeID--; // or
employee1.EmployeeID += 1; // and so on...
```

Snippet ps: the first line you have a single call to a `set` operation, but the lines below you have both a `get` call and after a `set` call.

Here some snipped code to you confirm and understand what I'm saying:

```
class Employee
{
    private int _employeeID;

    public int EmployeeId
    {
        get
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Employee.EmployeeId get operation was called.");
            return _employeeID;
        }
        set
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Employee.EmployeeId set operation was called.");
            _employeeID = value;
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var e = new Employee();

        e.EmployeeId++; // or any other exaple.
    }
}
```

If you run this code you'll get the output:

> The Employee.EmployeeId get operation was called.
>   The Employee.EmployeeId set operation was called.

Comment: this answer is very wrong and should be a comment at best.. and if it is `very wrong` as you have mentioned then post some code that supports your comment displaying how the OP should use getter and setter to assign values to a property..

Comment: This answer is base on the question  *it possible to use Console.ReadLine(), inside the set part of the property*, not in the code specifically.

Comment: it's totally possible but what you had stated as an answer yes but this is very wrong is not a good answer .. now that you edited the answer it looks 100% better.. however personally you should have shown the OP an example of both ..`1` the incorrect way vs `2` the correct way.. that's all I am trying to say..

Comment: Get it, I guess, please read again and tell if seems ok. I try to correct what you said.

Comment: take a look at @LuisLavien answer it's an excellent example on how to do it clear simple and concise

Comment: Thank you @Johnny Piazzi for your answer I think it is clear that I should NOT use this code and why it is wrong. I also would like to point out that it indeed answer my question wherever it is even possible, and I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter Employee ID:");

        var empID = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        var employee1 = new Employee
        {
            EmployeeID = empID
        };
    }
}
```

`Getters` and `Setters` should only be used to set/return whatever value the Property holds. You could also create private fields and set those with different methods. However, you won't call `Console.ReadLine()` from the class. The class is a representation of your entity.

Comment: Thank you for for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You are heading in a wrong direction.
The correct way is via `Main` method.

Or if you want to put the functionality in your class for whatever reason, it should be this way

```
class Employee
{
    protected int empID;
    public int EmployeeID 
    {
        get { return empId; }
    }
    //more code here
    public void AskEmployeeID()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter Employee ID:");
        this.empID = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

Now you can call this function on `Employee` object as `employee1.AskEmployeeID();`

Comment: Still a bad idea as you've now introduced a dependency to Console into your Employee class. It makes unit testing much more difficult not to mention makes reusing the Employee class outside of the console app nigh impossible (without a dose of refactoring.)

Comment: @Nate222 I don't think creating dependency is a concern for OP, it's an answer to a beginner and OP gonna stay long enough in console world for learning the way out.